# How much choice do we need for regularity of product of regular spaces ?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, gn.general-topology

It is usually stated that the (possibly uncountable) product
of regular topological spaces is regular. 
However the only proof that I know of this fact seems to use the full axiom of choice :

See [here](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Regularity_is_product-closed)
(proof based on Mukres' Topology p.197).

Do we really need AC (does this imply AC) ? Would it hold in ZF, or in ZF + a weaker form of choice ?

Answer (score 5):

The standard proof that the product of regular spaces is regular does not use the Axiom of Choice.

Suppose $X_i$ ($i \in I$) are regular spaces and let $X = \prod_{i \in I} X_i$. Given a point $x \in X$ and a basic neighborhood $U = \prod_{i \in I} U_i$ of that point, we can always find a basic subneighborhood $V = \prod_{i \in I} V_i$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V} \subseteq U$. Indeed, when $U_i = X_i$ let $V_i = X_i$ too. For the finitely many $i \in I$ such that $U_i \neq X_i$, pick a neighborhood $V_i$ of $x_i$ such that $\overline{V}_i \subseteq U_i$. This only involves making finitely many choices, so the Axiom of Choice is not necessary.

Comment: Francois, just tiny addition: the existence of the product space does of course require AC. I know it's silly to mention, but maybe that was the OP's real issue, 'uncountable product' an all...

Comment: Why would the existence of the product require choice?  The non-emptiness of the product requires choice, but if it's empty, it's regular anyways.